# Error with primary swatch in flutter project

Tags: android, flutter, dart

[image]

i have a red line when i select color  ,i think he can't recognize the chosen color

Comment: The type of `primarySwatch` is not `Color` .
The type is `MaterialColor` It is like color but with  its different shades.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`primarySwatch` require a `MaterialColor`.

[ThemeData](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ThemeData/ThemeData.html)

See [Turn any color to Material Color for flutter](https://medium.com/py-bits/turn-any-color-to-material-color-for-flutter-d8e8e037a837)

```dart
Map<int, Color> color = {
  50:Color.fromRGBO(136,14,79, .1),
  100:Color.fromRGBO(136,14,79, .2),
  200:Color.fromRGBO(136,14,79, .3),
  300:Color.fromRGBO(136,14,79, .4),
  400:Color.fromRGBO(136,14,79, .5),
  500:Color.fromRGBO(136,14,79, .6),
  600:Color.fromRGBO(136,14,79, .7),
  700:Color.fromRGBO(136,14,79, .8),
  800:Color.fromRGBO(136,14,79, .9),
  900:Color.fromRGBO(136,14,79, 1),
};


MaterialColor colorCustom = MaterialColor(0xFF880E4F, color);
```

And

```dart
theme: ThemeData(
  primarySwatch: colorCustom,
  bottomAppBarColor: colorCustom
),
```

[image: Example]

Answer (score 0):

Change the default primary theme color of Flutter widget components to any other custom theme color at once by using ThemeData. The default color of the Flutter app is blue color.

```
MaterialApp(
  theme: ThemeData(
      primarySwatch: Colors.purple
  ),
)
```

Full Example

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main(){
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
         primarySwatch: Colors.purple
      ),
      home: Home(),
    );
  }
}


class Home extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    return  Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar( 
              title: Text("Flutter Color Theme"),
          ),
          body: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
            alignment: Alignment.center,
             child: Column(
               children:[
                  ElevatedButton(
                     onPressed: (){

                     },
                     child: Text("Elevated Button"),
                  ),

                  ListTile(
                     leading: Checkbox(
                        value: true,
                        onChanged: (value){},
                     ),
                     title:Text("This is checkbox")
                  ),

                  ListTile(
                     leading: Radio(
                        groupValue: true,
                        value: true,
                        onChanged: (value){}, 
                     ),
                     title:Text("This is Radio")
                  )
               ]
             ),
          )
       );
  }
}
```

See here: [Flutter Campus](https://www.fluttercampus.com/guide/263/change-defaut-theme-color-flutter/)